# Extract Numbers after pattern

Tags: c#, regex

(50798.3 vol 1 of 14-page 113)

In the above string, to find everything before -page, I use

```
^([^-page]*)
```

I have tested it out [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/5ewSlTJ5Gg)

Now I have 2 problems:

1. How to extract 113 after -page.
2. How to remove the "(" in the beginning if it is present.  In some of my strings, "(" may not be present.

Kindly help.  I have to use this in my C# application.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? or do you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as:

`^\(?([^-]*)-page\s(\d+)`

The two captured groups `\1` or `$1` and `\2` or `$2` will contain the data that you want.

You can check it out here: http://www.rubular.com/r/vr70ge5FNx

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance sshashank124's answer by adding names to your groups

```
var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)-page\s(?<Page>\d+)";

var match = Regex.Match("(50798.3 vol 1 of 14-page 113)", regEx);

string description = match.Groups["Desc"].Value;
string page = match.Groups["Page"].Value;
```