# Regex Extract Match Groups

Tags: c#, regex

> (50798.3 vol 1 of 14-page 113)

The above is my clipboard content.  [As in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178424/extract-numbers-after-pattern), I extracted 50798.3 vol 1 of 14 and saved it in pdf_name and 113 as pagenumber.  This worked well.

```
            var current_clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)-page\s(?<Page>\d+)";
            var match = Regex.Match(current_clipboard, regEx);
            string pdf_name = match.Groups["Desc"].Value;
            string pagenumber = match.Groups["Page"].Value;
```

Now, for a variation of the clipboard content where the -page would be of the format _Page or _Pages, I have used the below and it is not working.  By not working, I mean when I use MessageBox.Show for pdf_name and pagenumber, the message box is displaying blank messages.  Also, when I test the RegEx, it is showing 3 [groups as here](http://www.rubular.com/r/yqmHIUzV9e).  I don't need the second match group.

```
            var current_clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_pag(e|es)\s(?<Page>\d+)";
            var match = Regex.Match(current_clipboard, regEx);
            string pdf_name = match.Groups["Desc"].Value;
            string pagenumber = match.Groups["Page"].Value;
```

So, I am doing something wrong.  Please help me save the correct values to pdf_name and pagenumber.

Edit#

@Jerry

I tried your version as below.

```
            var current_clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_pages?\s(?<Page>\d+)";
            var match = Regex.Match(current_clipboard, regEx);
            string pdf_name = match.Groups["Desc"].Value;
            string pagenumber = match.Groups["Page"].Value;
            MessageBox.Show(pdf_name);
            MessageBox.Show(pagenumber);
```

Unfortunately the message box is returning blank messages.

Comment: Does it have something to do with `_Page`/`_Pages` vs. `_page`/`_pages`

Comment: Thanks, will avoid adding tags in the future.

Comment: No, these are the variations.  Actually, clicking one checkbox uses one variation else the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex are by default, case sensitive, meaning that `p` will match only `p` and not `P`. If you want a case insensitive regex, then you can either use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` or the inline modifier `(?i)`, or you use `[Pp]` in your regex, which will match either `p` or `P` (but the other letters will be match in a case sensitive manner.

With the option, the line with `.Match` will change:

```
var match = Regex.Match(current_clipboard, regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

With the inline modifier, the regex will change:

```
var regEx = @"(?i)^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_pag(e|es)\s(?<Page>\d+)";
```

With the character class, the regex will change:

```
var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_[Pp]ag(e|es)\s(?<Page>\d+)";
```

To your next issue, the basic way to avoid a capture is to use a non-capture group. Here, you have `(e|es)` which is a capture group. Change that to `(?:e|es)`:

```
var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_[Pp]ag(?:e|es)\s(?<Page>\d+)";
```

Though really, you don't need an alternation here. You can use the `?` quantifier meaning 0 or 1 times:

```
var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_[Pp]ages?\s(?<Page>\d+)";
```

---

Example with the option and `?` quantifier:

```
var current_clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
var regEx = @"^\((?<Desc>[^-]*)_pages?\s(?<Page>\d+)";
var match = Regex.Match(current_clipboard, regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string pdf_name = match.Groups["Desc"].Value;
string pagenumber = match.Groups["Page"].Value;
```

And [here](http://regex101.com/r/mA8dN5)'s another regex tester site that supports this syntax for named capture groups.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the Regex editor.  When I tried the code on the editor it is working fine, but when I try it in Visual Studio, it is returning blank messages for pdf_name and pagenumber.  If you can, please look into it.  I have added the code that I used in my question under edit.

Comment: @vel2013 Does the current clipboard contain anything other than the description and pages? Might be that the `^` is not matching. `^` matches only at the beginning of a line. If that's so, then try removing it. Also, is there an opening parenthesis before the description? If not, remove `\(` as well from the start of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that, given you no longer have a `-` separator before your pages, your initial `[^-]*` pattern is gobbling up your whole string.

If underscores don't appear in your description, you should replace `[^-]*` with `[^_]*`. Alternatively, use [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) matching: `(?<Desc>.*?)`.

Comment: My description may or may not have underscores.

Comment: In that case, use lazy matching.

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing `(e|es)` as the 2nd group.

Change it to a `non-capturimg group`

```
(?:e|es)
```

> Non-Capturing Groups: (?: Often, you need parentheses in order to
>   write an expression that makes sense. Normally, parentheses capture
>   what they match. Non-capturing groups allow you to use parentheses
>   without capturing anything. Watch out, as the syntax closely resembles
>   that for a lookahead.
>
> Non-Capturing Group Pattern: (?:Bob) Matches Bob, but Bob is not
>   captured.

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html